# set cursor position DIV fixed center-bottom to target

Tags: jquery

my questions is How to **show div or box element** with position fixed center-bottom to click target

example :

```
<p>
  <button class="target-show">target show</button> 
  <button class="target-show">target show</button>
</p>

<hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr>
<hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr>

<div id="demo"></div>

<p>
  <button class="hidden-div">hidden div</button>
</p>
```

css :

```
p {
  text-align:center;
}
button {
  width : 50px;
}
#demo {
  display :none;
  padding : 25px;
  background : red ;
  width : 100px;
  height : 100px;
}
```

jquery :

```
$(function() {
    $(".target-show").click(function(e) {
        var target  =   $('.target-show');
            var div         =   $('#demo');
      var left      = e.clientX - target.width()/2;
      var top       = e.clientY - target.height()/2;
        div.css({'position': 'absolute', 'left': left, 'top': top}).show();
    });

      $(".hidden-div").click(function() { 
                $("#demo").hide();
        });
});
```

```js
$(function() {
    $(".target-show").click(function(e) {
     var target = $('.target-show');
   var div   = $('#demo');
      var left  = e.clientX - target.width()/2;
      var top   = e.clientY - target.height()/2;
        div.css({'position': 'absolute', 'left': left, 'top': top}).show();
    });
    
      $(".hidden-div").click(function() { 
       $("#demo").hide();
     });
});
```

```css
p {
  text-align:center;
}

button {
  width : 50px;
}

#demo {
  display :none;
  padding : 25px;
  background : red ;
  width : 100px;
  height : 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <button class="target-show">target show</button> 
  <button class="target-show">target show</button>
</p>

<hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr>
<hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr>

<div id="demo"></div>

<p>
  <button class="hidden-div">hidden div</button>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the red div to appear *centered-bottom* relative to the mouse pointer when user clicks, you have to use [`outerWidth()`](http://api.jquery.com/outerwidth/) and [`outerHeight()`](http://api.jquery.com/outerheight/) which is including not only the `div` width and height, but also the `padding:25px` from your CSS.

It would also include the border width...

And if you pass a `true` as argument, it will include the margins.
;)

```js
$(function() {
  $(".target-show").click(function(e) {
    var div   = $('#demo').show();
    var left  = e.clientX - (div.outerWidth()/2);
    var top   = e.clientY - (div.outerHeight());
    div.css({'position': 'absolute', 'left': left, 'top': top}).show();
  });

  $(".hidden-div").click(function() { 
    $("#demo").hide();
  });
});
```

```css
p {
  text-align:center;
}

button {
  width : 50px;
}

#demo {
  display :none;
  padding : 25px;
  background : red ;
  width : 100px;
  height : 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <button class="target-show">target show</button> 
  <button class="target-show">target show</button>
</p>

<hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr>
<hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr>

<div id="demo"></div>

<p>
  <button class="hidden-div">hidden div</button>
</p>
```